# Assert number of matching elements in collection via Hamcrest

Tags: java, unit-testing, hamcrest

I have a collection of matchers like `List<Matcher<?>> filters` and some collection of elements `List<Element> elementsToCheck`. I want to create an assertion that checks if there are **x** elements that match all filters, something like that:

```
public void checkMatch(List<Matcher<?>> filters, int expectedSize){         
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(elementsToCheck, ???);     
}
```

I wrote something like that:

```
final Iterator<Element> iterator = this.elements.iterator();
final List<Element> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    final Element element = iterator.next();
    boolean allMatches = true;
    for (final Matcher<?> matcher : this.filters) {
        if (!matcher.matches(element)) {
            allMatches = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (allMatches) {
        filtered.add(element);
    }
}

MatcherAssert.assertThat(filtered, 
Matchers.hasSize(this.expectedSize));
```

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

`org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.allOf` matcher can be used instead of the list of matchers. Then a test may look as follows (I test list of Strings as an example):

```
// given
Matcher<String> allOfMatcher = allOf(containsString("a"), containsString("b"));
long expectedNumberOfMatches = 2L;

// when
List<String> elementsToCheck = Arrays.asList("aa", "ab", "ba", "bb"); // substitute with some actual method call

// then
assertThat(elementsToCheck, notNullValue());
assertThat(elementsToCheck.stream().filter(allOfMatcher::matches).collect(Collectors.counting()), equalTo(expectedNumberOfMatches));
```

You can even pass the already existing list of matchers to overloaded version of `allOf` that takes `Iterable` as an argument.

```
private Matcher<Element> getAllOfMatcher(List<Matcher<? super Element>> matchers) {
    return CoreMatchers.allOf(matchers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understodd task right:
List elementsToCheck- collection of elements

this.filters - collection of Matchers

```
  elementsToCheck.stream()                                           
              .filter(element ->!this.filters.stream()
                                 .filter(matcher -> matcher.matches(element))                       
  .collect(Collectors.toList()).size() == this.filters.size())
  .collect(Collectors.toList()).size() == this.expectedSize
```